# Indecomposable vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, representation-theory

Let us define $V$ as a quotient space $\mathbb{K}[t]/(p^m)$, where $p$ is an irreducible polynomial. Condsider the linear operator $\phi\in Hom_{\mathbb{K}}(V,V)$, which sends each $q+(p^m)$ to $tq+(p^m)$.
 
I want to prove that there are no such subspaces $V_1,V_2\subset V$ that $\phi(V_i)\subset V_i$ and $V_1 \bigoplus V_2=V$.
First, I tried to show that there are no subspaces, invariant under $\phi$ (we admit $m\ge2$), but it is not true (really, $\{p^{m-1},tp^{m-1},t^2p^{m-1},...\}$ generates an invariant subspace $\ne V$).
Could you give me any hint?

Answer (score 1):

You can compute all $\phi$-invariant subspaces.

Assume that $W$ is $\phi$-invariant. Then $W$ is actually an ideal of $V$.
In fact for $q\in \mathbb{K}[t]$ we have that $qW=q(\phi)(W)\subset W$.

Let $p^k$ be the smallest power of $p$ that divides all elements of $W$.
Then there is $p^kf\in W$ such that $(f,p)=1$. This implies that $(f,p^m)=1$. Using Euclid's algorithm there are $a,b\in \mathbb{K}[t]$ such that $fa+p^mb=1$. Therefore $p^k=p^k(1-p^mb)=p^kfa\in W$. This shows that $W$ is the ideal generated by $p^k$.

But now the result follows be cause all the $\phi$-invariant subspaces of $V$ are nested $\{0\}\subset p^{m-1}V\subset p^{m-2}V\subset...\subset pV\subset V$.
Therefore, the only way to choose two of them with intersection only at $0$, is $V=V\oplus \{0\}$.